# How to implement 1:1 Chat-to-Custom Object History with Quickblox in Javascript

Tags: quickblox

I have been to this [link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/1:1_Chat_history) which explains how to automatically save chat history for android and ios in the Custom Objects module.

However my app is cordova and therefore written in javascript. I tried sending a message with the class_name and quickblox session token in the extension of the message, but this did not automatically create the chat history as the link suggests...Is this not implemented for javascript yet?

```
var message = {
  body: 'hi',
  type: 'chat',
  extension: {
    class_name: 'chat_messages',
    token: token
    }
  }

chatService.sendMessage(1234,message);
```

Also, I have created a class in custom objects called chat_messages with 3 fields, receiver_id message and dateSent. They are int, string and int respectively.

Comment: Are you using the Chat 2.0 branch of the SDK? https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/blob/chat2.0/quickblox.min.js

Comment: @AlexBass I was using the one downloaded from the javascript sdk website here: http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript near the bottom of the page. I've now deleted that and am using the one you linked but it is still not automatically adding a chat history

Comment: @AlexBass any suggestions? I went to your link and downloaded the `quickblox.min.js` from the branch chat2.0 and then I downloaded the `quickblox.chat.min.js` from the same branch. It still does not automatically create chat history. Can you let me know if there is someting wrong with my implementation? Should the class name and token be in extension or outside extension? Alternatively if it is not automatic then I will implement it manually but I'd prefer not to. Please let me know

Comment: @AlexBass is there somewhere I am supposed to turn on automatic chat history?